# Proguard broke react native android

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, proguard

After enabling **proguard** in my react native project, I've been getting countless notes and errors from all the packages, `com.facebook.react`, `okhttp3`, `okio`, and every other 3rd party library that I'm using including `org.reactnative.camera`, `com.lwansbrough.RCTCamera`, `com.horcrux.svg` and more. Shouldn't the default proguard rules already take care of some of the default packages?

After countless hours looking for solution that includes the obvious `-dontnote` and `-dontwarn`, as well as attempting to `-keep` all the classes mentioned, each time I manage to get rid of a couple of the warnings there is always more warnings.

Do I really have to manually go through every single reference to use proguard? Sometimes I don't even know which class to keep and ignore when using other libraries. Please help.

```
Note: there were 4 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 1 references to unknown class members.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
Note: there were 835 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Note: there were 70 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Warning: there were 1620 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Thread(Tasks limiter_14): destruction
```